# Site w/ Addon Domain doesn't show CSS

Tags: multisite, css

I have a website with its main domain name and an add-on domain.

When I access the Wordpress site from the main domain, CSS/JS loads without any issues.

When I access the site through the add-on domain, CSS/JS doesn't load, however the links work!

My .htaccess file looks as follows:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Do I need anything else?

Also, my hotlink protection of my site is disabled.

Any help or pointers will be appreciated!!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With add-on domain you probably mean a domain alias, right?

Set your `WP_HOME` and `WP_SITEURL` to a dynamically value in your `wp-config.php`.

This is how it's done, I use this code all the time it also will define some other constants.

```
$root='public_html'; //Set this to the DocumentRoot.
define('FTP_USER','<username>'); //Replace <username> with your FTP username.
define('FTP_PASS','<password>'); //Replace <password> the password for that FTP user.

/*## GET CONFIGURATION INFORMATION DYNAMICALLY ##*/
$addr=$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
$name=$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$host=$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$https=$_SERVER['HTTPS'];
$protocol=(!empty($https)&&$https!=='off'||$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']===443)?'https://':'http://';
$abspath=(strpos(getcwd(),'/wp-admin')!==FALSE)?substr(getcwd(),0,strrpos(getcwd(),'/wp-admin')):getcwd();
$relpath=substr($abspath,strrpos($abspath,$root)+strlen($root));

/*## STORE THE DYNAMIC INFORMATION ##*/
define('WP_HOME',$protocol.$host.$relpath);
define('WP_SITEURL',$protocol.$name.$relpath); ;
define('FTP_BASE',$abspath);
define('FTP_HOST',$addr);
```

Any feedback on my code is always welcome!

Comment: this is absolutely brilliant! Many thanks for your help. Actually, I didn't have to define the FTP_User and FTP_PASS variables, as the rest of the code works without any issues! Thanks, again.